# parsing string to time is not the same as the original time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I was having a problem with finding records by using one of the object property which is of class `Time`.

Turns out that when I pass in the time as a `params` to my controller, which in turn sends it to the model... the `time` object I'm sending gets stringified.

So I thought I will just convert it back to Time either by `Time.parse(<stringified time>)` or `<stringified time>.to_time` - (Using rails)

But my test keeps failing, so I decided to do some look into what was going on there.

This was what I found out:

```
2.2.0 :003 > a = Time.now
 => 2015-10-14 20:50:19 +0100 
2.2.0 :004 > b = a.to_s
 => "2015-10-14 20:50:19 +0100" 
2.2.0 :005 > c = Time.parse b
 => 2015-10-14 20:50:19 +0100 
2.2.0 :006 > c == a
 => false 
2.2.0 :007 > a.class
 => Time 
2.2.0 :008 > c.class
 => Time 
2.2.0 :015 > a - c
 => 0.951439 
2.2.0 :016 > d = b.to_time
 => 2015-10-14 20:50:19 +0100 
2.2.0 :017 > c - d
 => 0.0
```

My confusion is mostly from the line: `a - c` which gave me `0.951439`. Where did this difference come from?

Most importantly, how do I make these two to be equal? Thanks much, all.

Comment: Such a nice question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason:

> Since Ruby 1.9.2, Time implementation uses a signed 63 bit integer,
>   Bignum or Rational. The integer is a **number of nanoseconds** since the
>   Epoch which can represent 1823-11-12 to 2116-02-20. When Bignum or
>   Rational is used (before 1823, after 2116, under nanosecond), Time
>   works slower as when integer is used.

And if you run `a = Time.now` you got N seconds since the Epoch **plus** P nanoseconds. But when you run `Time.parse b` you got same number seconds but with **zero** nanosecond. This is what you're looking for.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
[1] pry(main)> a = Time.now
=> 2015-10-14 23:41:12 +0300
[2] pry(main)> a.nsec
=> 733355000
[3] pry(main)> Time.parse(a.to_s).nsec
=> 0
```

So you have to avoid this nano stuff. For instance you can write something like that:

```
[16] pry(main)> a = Time.at(Time.now.to_i)
=> 2015-10-14 23:47:59 +0300
[17] pry(main)> a.nsec
=> 0
```

Comment: wow! Thanks, Arsen, that is an eye opener. However, seeing that the database gets automatically populated with all this nano stuff, is there any way I can preserve(get back) the `nsec` when converting the time back from either string or int?

Comment: No. You cannot because if you convert time with nanosecs to string or integer you will lose this information and you cannot restore it in the future. But you can call `a.to_f` and save this float. This float contains seconds and nano seconds and you can restore Time from it.

Comment: Thanks much. this has really been of great help :)